# How to compile SCIP in Visual Studio

Tags: scip

I have spent several days to try to make the SCIP work with C++/Windows 7. I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio, 2008-2013.

I am kind of being new to the SCIP. I read through the installation procedure and try to install the SCIP. But I can't understand the installation procedure clearly. I looked through the callable library example, and I can't find the SCIP.h. Can anyone tell me how to install the SCIP with VC step by step, and set up an example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is the [OPTI-Toolbox](http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/), which builds SCIP as a Matlab Executable, at least some steps with VS. Alternatively, you could try to build it with mingw or cygwin.

Comment: I cannot give you detailed instructions on how to set up SCIP within VisualStudio, since most SCIP developers work with Linux build tools. You might try disabling ZIMPL support because getting ZIMPL set up in VC is apparently quite difficult. Furthermore, you should try to get SoPlex running first.
I can only recommend to develop under Linux. Included in the code base, there are some very helpful scripts for testing and evaluating SCIP that won't run on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much. In order to avoid to compile, I try to use the Binary scip-3.1.0.win.x86.msvc.opt.spx, which includes ,dll, .lib and .exe files. I have run some  examples and try to solve the problem with the LP solver soplex. I had some questions.  Is the "scipoptsuite-3.1.0\scip-3.1.0\src\lpi\lpi_spx.cpp" is included when generating the above .dll and .lib.  How can I access the class SPxSCIP in the lpi_spx.cpp in my own .cpp file. Since the class SPxSCIP is only declared in the lpi_spx.cpp, and not been declared in other .h head files. I can send my own .cpp if required.

Comment: lpi_spx is the lp interface for SoPlex. This is the default LP solver and is contained in the suite. If you want to use the lpi you don't need to specify the LP solver. You only call the general lpi methods, e.g. SCIPlpiCreate() or SCIPlpiAddRows(). Please have a look at the documentation: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/lpi_8h.php

Comment: If you only want to access the LPi then why don't you work with the SoPlex library directly? This should be easier.
Also: Please consider accepting these comments as answers and start a new question to avoid long discussion in comments.